how to configure network and install a v2ray config?
I have no idea about how network systems work in operating systems.
but I need to connect to a v2ray config to work. I cant even install most of the packages.
I installed a v2ray client and added like 30 configs but none of them work.
and I have no idea to what to put here as details to get help.
I think i have to configure my network settings so the v2ray configs work.
can anyone help me by explaining things ?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
